# How can I get pstricks and tikz to work in the same document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pst-barcode

I'm trying to get a `\psbarcode` in my document which also uses a `tikzpicture`. I'm using `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}`, but---even though the document compiles and shows a document afterwards---the barcode doesn't show up... Any ideas what I should do *exactly*?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You might find that people are more willing to work on this problem if you post a minimum working example that replicates the issue.  See [this post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe/3301#3301).

Answer (score 5):

This works for me with `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile` assuming that the following is saved as `myfile.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle(2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pspicture}
    \psbarcode[scalex=.75,scaley=.75]
    {Harish Kumar}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

I think some more help is needed in compiling as per the comments. In TeXworks, Go to `Edit` → `Preferences`. The following window appears:

[image]

Here click `Typesetting` tab. In this click `+` button (shown with arrow above). In the small new tool window that opens,  enter the following values:

[image]

Click OK in all and come out. Now compile with `pdflatexshell` by selecting it in the drop down menu next to green arrow.

[image]

Hope it will be useful.

## Flying with arara

You can also use the tex automation tool arara. [Download and install](https://github.com/cereda/arara) `arara`. In texlive, it comes along with by default. Add a menu entry in TeXworks for arara. The elegantly written manual has a section on how to do this for different editors including TeXworks. Follow the steps above (for `pdflatexshell`) and in the new tool window type like this:

[image]

Now press `OK` whenver you find it and you will have a new menu in the drop down list next to green arrow. Choose `arara` in it. Add the line `% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes}` like

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle(2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pspicture}
    \psbarcode[scalex=.75,scaley=.75]
    {Harish Kumar}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

in your code and press green button:

[image]

Comment: What the hell does that mean? How _exactly_ do I do that?

Comment: @GreenandWhite `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile`

Comment: And what does that mean? How do I implement this string of code? And where? Exactly... You must understand, I don't know what you're telling me.

Comment: Here is my code: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173370/how-can-i-get-a-royal-mail-psbarcode-below-addresses-in-letter

Comment: Compile it where? What do you mean by compile? What is that line of code? I just type my code in TeXworks and press the green button.

Comment: Where _exactly_ does "`pdflatex --shell-escape myfile`" go?

Comment: @GreenandWhite You can run it in your shell/cmd instead of pressing the button. Or you can change the settings of your IDE to use the command.

Comment: @GreenandWhite See the edit.

Comment: I'd be wary about adding `-shell-escape` to the default `pdflatex` engine; I'd define a new engine (menu entry, if you prefer) with `-shell-escape` enabled. Or, of course, I'd use arara.

Comment: @egreg I totally agree :). I will add an `arara` option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle(2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \psbarcode[scalex=.75,scaley=.75]{foo}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am running with xelatex. I don't get that result.

Comment: what system do you use. Put `\listfiles` as first line into the source and show the file list which will be at the end of the log file.

Comment: TeXworks on a Mac

Comment: which version of MacTeX? Look into the log file (the first line)

Comment: Version 3.1415926-2.50.9999.3 XeTeX

Comment: can you show the pdf output??